# Correct Permissions for hsperfdata in /tmp/ on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I noticed that the jps monitoring program does not work properly if this directory in /tmp/ has incorrect permissions. I can't seem to find the correct permissions for this folder in the documentation. So far I've noticed chmod 750 and 755 seem to both allow JPS to work but I'd like a more exhaustive list.

Answer (score 0):

if the hsperfdata_* remain empty, remove the folders and restart the java applications. The folders are created properly

```
rm -rf /tmp/hsperfdata_*
```

if an application can't access the files insed the hsperfdata_* folders, run them as root.